# Record IoT device activity to secure domain for debugging

Tags: debugging, logging, ssh, iot, http-proxy

I have an IoT device (standalone) that I need to debug Wifi connectivity (if we're sending up the right requests, or if they're coming down proper). I have 5 secure domains that I need to log all traffic to and from. I can get any new hardware/software needed, but I need to basically store all activity and then use a service to upload remotely for comparison on the server side.

Any great suggestions on best approaches for this? I can't install a proxy on the device, so Charles/Wireshark (my regular go-tos) are out. I can buy a router and setup DD-WRT or something, or just root a laptop with a special brew of linux.

Please advise. I need to get the setup put together as quickly as possible. Trying to debug a serious problem.

Comment: How are the IoT devices communicating, and what protocols are they using? You're looking for an analysis tool that can do a man-in-the-middle (or monkey in the middle) attack on your own infrastructure.

Comment: IoT using TCP to 5 diff secure URLs. Https. UDP local, but I'm only interested in the TCP remote data.